# Extend body background image/body not as tall as html

Tags: html, css

I've got two background images, one on the html, and the other on the body. But for some reason, the body one does not stretch to the full height of the window, as it should. Or, more specifically, there's about a...maybe 50px space where the body's BG does not show. I do have a margin on the bottom of the content (which doesn't seem to show, but is not a big deal) that is 50px, but I've deleted it and still the problem persists. [You can see the problem here.](http://a.yfrog.com/img257/3710/problemgs.png) I can't quite figure out why. Any ideas? Maybe I'm missing something fundamental...

EDIT:

I have, yes. I thought it might of been that HTML Image might be too big, and it didn't want to stretch the body's image too much, but that doesn't make sense, so.

I meant to post the code, but didn't have it on hand. Here it is now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-///W3C///DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional///EN" "http:///www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../_script/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../_script/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_script/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_script/page_photo.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a.single_image").fancybox();
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*v Reset v*/
            html,body,div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,del,em,img,
            small,strike,strong,sub,sup,ul,ol,fieldset,form,label,legend,
            table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,optgroup,option
            {   margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;
                text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;
                text-decoration: none; list-style: none;
            }
            /*^ Reset ^*/
            html
            {   height: 100%; min-width: 1000px;
                background: url("../_images/Wall.jpg");
                margin: 0; padding: 0;
            }
            body
            {   height: 100%; min-width: 1000px;
                background: url("../_images/NAV_BG-HALF.png") repeat-y;
                font: 300 12px/22.0px Palatino Linotype, Palatino, Book Antiqua, Georgia, serif;
                color: #bdb798;
            }
            a:link              { color: #bdb798; text-decoration: none; }
            a:visited           { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; }
            a:hover             { color: #d8e5c2; text-decoration: none; }
            a:active                { color: #a5a49f;  text-decoration: none; }
            #nav a:link         { color: #bdb798; text-decoration: none; }
            #nav a:visited      { color: #9e9c7a; text-decoration: none; }
            #nav a:hover        { color: #d8e5c2; text-decoration: none; }
            #nav a:active       { color: #9e9c7a; text-decoration: none; }

            #header
            {   height: 80px;
                margin-bottom: 50px; padding: 10px;
                background: #2e2d29;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                background-image: url("../_images/head-bg.png")
            }

            @import url("constant.css");
            #nav
            {   width: 119px; height: 528px;            /*minus padding+border*/
                margin-right: 60px; padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid black; border-left: 0;
                background: #2a2727;
                *padding: 10px 0 10px                   /*IE*/
                *width: 119px;                              /*IE*/
                float: left;
            }
            #nav ul { margin: 0 10px; }
            #nav hr
            {   margin: 5px -10px;
                color: #848678;
                border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                *margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;
                *width: 99px;
            }
            #content
            {   min-height: 90%; overflow: hidden; 
                padding: 0 30px;
                border: 1px solid black; border-right: 0;
                background: #2a2727;
                *padding: 0 30px 0 30px;                            /* ???? */
                *font-size: 20px;
            }
            #content hr
            {   margin: 0 -30px;
                clear: both; 
                border-top: 1px solid #010101; border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
                *margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
                *width: 106%;
            }
            #content .bio
            {   width: 70%; max-height: 220px; overflow: auto;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 0; padding: 10px;
                float: right; 
            }
            #content h2.author { margin: 5px 0; text-align: right; *font-size: 20px; }
            #content .bio p { line-height: 1.25; text-align: right; }
            #content .work
            {   width: 100%; height: 660px; overflow: auto;
                padding: 10px;
                clear: both;
            }
            #content .work img { vertical-align: center; border: 4px double grey; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="../_images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            Photography
            <ul>
                <li><a href="google.com">Beth Balmforth</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">Kristen Popcheff</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">Krystle Parker</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">Renee Blanchord</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">-RESERVED-</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">-RESERVED-</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            Poetry
            <ul>
                <li>Rebecca R. Pierce</li>
                <li>Justin Louras</li>
                <li>-RESERVED-</li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <a href="../about.html">Home</a><br />
            <a href="../about.html">About</a><br/>
            <a href="../about.html">Submit</a><br />
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2 class="author">Beth Balmforth</h2>
            <div class="work">
                <img src="-photo-images/beth-balmforth_01.jpg" alt="Get 'em Tiger by Beth Balmforth" title="Get 'em Tiger by Beth Balmforth" />
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="bio">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dui odio, pulvinar luctus gravida in, varius ac est. Sed dapibus, felis sed placerat dignissim, urna magna egestas ante, aliquet tincidunt lacus ligula eu dui. Pellentesque pellentesque magna sed tortor ultricies lobortis. Mauris ultrices iaculis est, id vestibulum dolor molestie at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas rhoncus gravida neque, vitae posuere ipsum sodales sed. Cras adipiscing sagittis magna id varius. Quisque ut ligula eget justo volutpat adipiscing quis ut purus. Proin sollicitudin velit ac justo dictum adipiscing. Curabitur at sodales est. Praesent aliquam volutpat est, vel dignissim sapien dignissim non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a tiny image is a bad substitute for showing your code. Just plunk in what you've been working on so we can help you out.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or live example of your code and strip down your test case to the necessary code.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```